# Hacer click en un Mark para que se abra en Google Maps? Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

es posible que al hacer click en algun "mark" de mi app, este pueda redireccionarse a la App de Google Maps?

[image: Markers google maps]

```
public class UbicacionFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap map;
public UbicacionFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ubicacion, container, false);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;

    LatLng a = new LatLng(25.666376, -100.26546559999997);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options.position(a).title("HR DESECHABLES GUADALUPE");
    options.position(a).snippet("José Sixto Verduzco 800, Central de Abastos, 67147 Monterrey, N.L.");
    map.addMarker(options);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(a));

    LatLng d = new LatLng(25.5920038565153, -100.00365257263184 );
    MarkerOptions options3 = new MarkerOptions();
    options3.position(d).title("HR DESECHABLES CADEREYTA");
    options3.position(d).snippet("Av. Benito Juárez, 67450 Cadereyta Jiménez, N.L, México ");
    map.addMarker(options3);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(d));

    LatLng f = new LatLng( 22.7619524, -102.54727409999998);
    MarkerOptions options5 = new MarkerOptions();
    options5.position(f).title("HR DESECHABLES ZACATECAS");
    options5.position(f).snippet("José López Portillo 1, Tres Cruces, 98064 Zacatecas, Zac., México");
    map.addMarker(options5);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(f));

    LatLng g = new LatLng(25.747448 , -100.198314 );
    MarkerOptions options6 = new MarkerOptions();
    options6.position(g).title("HR DESECHABLES APODACA");
    options6.position(g).snippet("Blvrd Julian Treviño Elizondo 222A, El Milagro, 66634 Cd Apodaca, N.L., México");
    map.addMarker(options6);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(g));


}}
```

Comment: Quieres que te de la opción de ir a google maps al hacer click en las direcciones que tienes predeterminadas ?

Comment: Si así es. Quiero que al hacer click en alguna dirección se abra Google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

San Google te da la opción en la esquina inferior.

*1. Te muestro en mi app tengo esta* **dirección predeterminada**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*2. Ahora al pulsar la dirección(El market) en la parte inferior en la esquina te muestra*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entre el + y - (El zoom) y el compartir es la opción de ir a la `Google maps` con tu dirección.

Comment: Vaya, esa parte la tenia oculta debajo de un menú y la pase por alto, gracias.

Comment: De nada, que bueno que te haya ayudado. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar un listener `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` para detectar un click en el marcador y abrir la url que deseas:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```